# Clojure printing a list without parentheses?

Tags: clojure

Is there a built-in function to print the items of a list without top-level parentheses, or would there be a better way to write

```
(defn println-list
  "Prints a list without top-level parentheses, with a newline at the end"
  [alist]
  (doseq [item alist]
    (print (str item " ")))
  (print "\n"))
```

to get an output of

```
user=> (println-list '(1 2 3 4))
1 2 3 4 
nil
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(apply println '(1 2 3 4 5))
1 2 3 4 5
nil
```

From the [Clojure docs for `apply`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/apply):

```
Usage: (apply f args)
       (apply f x args)
       (apply f x y args)
       (apply f x y z args)
       (apply f a b c d & args)
Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening
arguments to args.
```

Answer (score 4):

in clojure-contrib.string you have the function join,

```
user=> (require '[clojure.contrib.string :as string])
nil
user=> (string/join " " '(1 2 3 4 4))
"1 2 3 4 4"
user=> (println (string/join " " '(1 2 3 4 4)))
1 2 3 4 4
nil
```